# How many nonnegative integer solutions are there to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 18$ with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many nonnegative integer solutions are there to the equation 
>   $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 18$ with $$−2\leq x_3 \leq 4\\0 \leq x_2 \leq 5\\3 \leq x_1 \leq8\\ −3 \leq x_4 \leq 13$$

when its in is simple form its easy to solve that but here in this kind of question how i solve it ?

Comment: If you say "non-negative," isn't $-2\leq x_3\leq 4$ a bit redundant - can't you set $x_3\leq 4$?

Comment: nice so i can say all like that ? 
x1≤5 and x4≤16 ?

Comment: If the question really says "non-negative," then yes.

Comment: Could you provide the exact wording of the question?  The question would make more sense if it said "How many integer solutions are there to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 18$ with $ 3 \leq x_1 \leq 8$, $0 \leq x_2 \leq 5$, $-2 \leq x_3 \leq 4$, and $-3 \leq x_4 \leq 13$.

Comment: That was my intention I was wrong in translation from the original language

Comment: I am interested in solving this question.  Can the answer be provided for this qyestion

Comment: May I suggest removing "nonnegative"?

Answer (score 1):

I never miss a chance to recommend a good book. ["How to Count"](https://www.amazon.co.uk/How-Count-Introduction-Combinatorics-Applications/dp/3319355082/) covers the relevant material and even more and it's a good book indeed.

Now to the problem. Assuming mistranslating "nonnegative" has a higher likelihood than copy and pasting math expressions, twice (one for "$-2 \leq ...$" and one for "$-3 \leq ...$") I will stick to the following version:

> How many integer solutions are there to the equation ...

This class of problems is solved with what is called [generating functions](https://math.illinoisstate.edu/day/courses/old/305/contentgeneratingfunctions.html). First of all
$$−2\leq x_3 \leq 4 \Leftrightarrow 0 \leq x_3+2 \leq 6$$
$$−3\leq x_4 \leq 13 \Leftrightarrow 0 \leq x_4+3 \leq 16$$
So, with a substitution like $y_1=x_1, y_2=x_2, y_3=x_3+2, y_4=x_4+3$ the problem is equivalent to
$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=23$$
$$3\leq y_1 \leq 8$$
$$0\leq y_2 \leq 5$$
$$0\leq y_3 \leq 6$$
$$0\leq y_4 \leq 16$$

The generating function for this problem is 
$$(y^3+y^4+...+y^8)(y^0+y^1+...+y^5)(y^0+y^1+...+y^6)(y^0+y^1+...+y^{16})$$
the coefficient near the $y^{23}$ term is the answer, [which is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(y%5E3%2By%5E4%2By%5E5%2By%5E6%2By%5E7%2By%5E8)*(y%5E0%2By%5E1%2By%5E2%2By%5E3%2By%5E4%2By%5E5)*(y%5E0%2By%5E1%2By%5E2%2By%5E3%2By%5E4%2By%5E5%2By%5E6)*(y%5E0%2By%5E1%2By%5E2%2By%5E3%2By%5E4%2By%5E5%2By%5E6%2By%5E7%2By%5E8%2By%5E9%2By%5E10%2By%5E11%2By%5E12%2By%5E13%2By%5E14%2By%5E15%2By%5E16)) $232$.