# How many possibilities?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a vector $x=(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1})$ with $x_i\in\{0,1,2\}$ for all $i=0,1,...,n-1$.

Define
$$
x'=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_i,
$$
then
$$
0\leq x'\leq n\cdot 2..
$$

I would like to know how many possibilities of vectors there are, for fixed $0\leq m\leq n\cdot 2$, to have
$$
x'=m.
$$

I think, for example, for $x'=0$ and $x'=n\cdot 2$, we only have one possibility, namely $(0,...,0)$ and $(2,...,2)$. But maybe there is some general formula.

I don’t know whether there is some Trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why John Don didn't post this as an answer. This is a combinatorial problem, covered by generating functions (for example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2514510/how-many-solutions-are-there-to-xyz-14-where-x-y-z-are-all-non-negative-in) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477467/how-many-nonnegative-integer-solutions-are-there-to-the-equation-x-1x-2x-3x/) and a really [good reading here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/How-Count-Introduction-Combinatorics-Applications/dp/3319355082/)).
So, we want 
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} x_i =m$$
$$0\leq x_i\leq 2, \forall x_i=0..n-1$$
The generating function is 
$$(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2)...(1+x+x^2)=(1+x+x^2)^n$$
and the coefficient near $x^{m}$ term is the answer. Considering [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem):
$$(1+x+x^2)^n=\sum\limits_{k_1+k_2+k_3=n}\binom{n}{k_1,k_2,k_3}1^{k_1}\cdot x^{k_2}\cdot x^{2k_3}=\\
\sum\limits_{k_1+k_2+k_3=n}\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!} x^{k_2+2k_3}$$
In other words, the answer is
$$\sum\limits_{k_1+k_2+k_3=n\\k_2+2k_3=m}\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!}$$

Comment: Yes ... true, thank you for pointing out! Fixing ...

Comment: Denoting this sum by $C(n,m)$, i.e. $$C(n,m):=\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3=n\\k_2+2k_3=m}\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!}$$, I think that $$\frac{1}{3^n}\sum_{m=0}^{2n}C(n,m)x^{2n}=x^{2n}$$ since $\sum_{m=0}^{2n}C(n,m)=3^n$. Am I right?

Comment: @John_Doe I looks so, from $(1+x+x^2)^n=\sum\limits_{k_1+k_2+k_3=n}\binom{n}{k_1,k_2,k_3}1^{k_1}\cdot x^{k_2}\cdot x^{2k_3}$ just by $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The expression providing the result you need is
$$
I_n(m)=\sum_{x_0=0}^2\cdots \sum_{x_{n-1}=0}^2 \delta_{\sum_i x_i,m}\ ,
$$
where $\delta_{a,b}=1$ if $a=b$ and $=0$ otherwise. Basically this is a counting device: you get a '$+1$' for every configuration $\mathbf{x}$ such that the sum of the components is equal to $m$.
Using the integral representation
$$
\delta_{a,b}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\xi}{2\pi}e^{\mathrm{i}\xi (a-b)}
$$
you get
$$
I_n(m)=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\xi}{2\pi}e^{\mathrm{i}\xi m}\left(\sum_{x=0}^2 e^{-\mathrm{i}\xi x}\right)^n=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\xi}{2\pi}e^{\mathrm{i}\xi m}(1+e^{-\mathrm{i}\xi}+e^{-2\mathrm{i}\xi})^n\ .
$$
Expanding with the multinomial theorem, you can get a more explicit expression. Mathematica can handle this integral for specific values of $m$ and $n$. For example, for $m=38$ and $n=29$ you get $I_n(m)=774369291150$.

Comment: Nice solution, though I personally feel that this is a bit of an overkill; there are far simpler methods that would give a solution that could be calculated in WolframAlpha, for example. $\\$E.g. we could observe that, the 'answer' the OP seeks is the coefficient of $x^m$ in $(1 + x + x^2)^n$. Plugging into WolframAlpha then gives the solution as it does in your answer. (I haven't posted this as an answer, as I don't feel it is particularly complete or satsfactory enough to be a full answer.)

Comment: @Pierpaolo Is it possible to compute $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log (\frac{1}{3^n}\sum_{m=0}^{2n}I_n(m)\cdot c_m)$, where $c_m$ is some constant depending on $m$?

Comment: @JohnDon I have the same question to your answer. By $a(n,m)$ denote the coefficient of $x^m$ in $(1+x+x^2)^n$. Is it then possible to determine $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(\frac{1}{3^n}\sum_{m=0}^{2n}a(n,m)\cdot c_m)$?

Comment: @JohnDon By the way: If I see it right, the coefficient of $x^m$ in $(1+x+x^2)^n$ is the multinomial coefficient $\binom{n}{n_1,n_2,n_3}$ with $n_1+n_2+n_3=n$ and $n_2+2n_3=m$. Here, $n_1$ is the number of zeros, $n_2$ the number of ones and $n_3$ the number of twos.

Comment: @John_Doe That observation is correct; with regards to your follow-up question, it is somewhat hard to say with no knowledge of what $c_m$ is. You say it is a constant (depending on $m$), but as it is inside a sum in which $m$ varies, this is like saying that $a(n,m)$ is just a constant that depends on $n$ and $m$.

Comment: @John_Doe Sorry, I was incorrect. It has to be $c_{2k+m}$ for some fixed $k$ and I have $c\lambda^{2k+m}\leq c_{2k+m}\leq d\lambda^{2k+m}$. Here $c$ and $d$ are constants and $\lambda$ is the largest (in absolute value) eigenvalue of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. I think its not that important where this comes from. My question is if we can compute $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{c\lambda^{2k}}{3^n}\sum_{m=0}^{2n}a(n,m)\lambda^m\right)$, c constant.