# Is it possible to compute $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{c\cdot\lambda^{2k}}{3^n}\sum_{m=0}^{2n}C(n,m)\cdot\lambda^m\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\lambda$ be the largest (in absolute value) root of $x^3-x^2-1$, which is
$\lambda\approx 1,466$, and $k\in\mathbb{N}_0=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ fixed.

Consider vectors $x$ of length $n$ the form
$$
x=(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}),\qquad x_i\in\{0,1,2\}\text{ for }i=0,1,\ldots,n-1.\quad (*)
$$
By $j(x)$ denote the sum of the components, i.e.
$$
j(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_i.
$$
We then have 
$$
0\leq j(x)\leq 2n.
$$
By $C(n,m)$ denote the coefficient of $x^m$ in $(1+x+x^2)^n$ which is the multinomial coefficient
$$
C(n,m)=\binom{n}{m_1,m_2,m_3}\text{ with }\sum_{i=1}^3m_i=n\text{ and }m_2+2m_3=m.
$$

($C(n,m)$ is the number of possible vectors $x$ of length $n$ of type $(*)$ such that $j(x)=m$, where $m_1$ is the number of zeros, $m_1$ is the number of ones and $m_3$ is the number of twos.)

> > I would like to know whether it is possible to determine
> >     $$
> > \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{c\cdot\lambda^{2k}}{3^n}\sum_{m=0}^{2n}C(n,m)\cdot\lambda^m\right),
> > $$
> >     where $c$ is some constant.

---

Unfortunately, I have no real idea how to compute this.

For an upper estimation, my idea would be to use that 
$$\sum_{m=0}^{2n}C(n,m)\leq\sum_{m_1+m_2+m_3=n}\binom{n}{m_1,m_2,m_3}=3^n
$$
and 
$$
\max_{0\leq m\leq 2n}\lambda^m=\lambda^{2n}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{c\lambda^{2k}}{3^n}\sum_{m=0}^{2n}C(n,m)\lambda^m\leq\frac{c\lambda^{2k}}{3^n}\lambda^{2n}\sum_{m=0}^{2n}C(n,m)\leq c\lambda^{2k+2n}.
$$

Taking logarithm, dividing by $n$ and taking the limit superior, I therefore get
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{c\cdot\lambda^{2k}}{3^n}\sum_{m=0}^{2n}C(n,m)\cdot\lambda^m\right)\leq 2\log\lambda.
$$

In case this might be correct: Maybe it is also possible to get $2\log\lambda$ as a lower bound?

*By the way: I exported this question from the comments of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533874/how-many-possibilities).*

Comment: What is $k$ in your big displayed equation?

Comment: k is some fixed number $k\in\mathbb{N}_0=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $C(n, m)$ is the coefficient of $x^m$ in $(1+x+x^2)^n$,
$$\sum_{m=0}^{2n}C(n,m)\lambda^m=(1+\lambda+\lambda^2)^n.$$
It is therefore not difficult to see that your sequence actually converges, with limit equal to $\log\left(\frac{1+\lambda+\lambda^2}3\right)$.

Comment: Concretely, I have problems to see that $(1+\lambda+\lambda^2)^n=\sum_{m_1+m_2+m_3=n}\binom{n}{m_1,m_2,m_3}\lambda^{m_2}\cdot\lambda^{2m_3}=\sum_{m=0}^{2n}C(n,m)\lambda^m$. The first equality is the multinomial theorem. But the second equality is hard for me to understand.

Comment: Isn't this by definition...?

Comment: Also, I've added a small edit to my answer as originally I had left out the logarithm from the limit. Apologies.

Comment: I think not. Because $C(n,m)$ is the multinomial coefficient $\binom{n}{m_1,m_2,m_3}$ with $m_1+m_2+m_3=n$ and $m_2+2m_3=m$. So the sum on the left hand side has much more summands than the sum on the right hand side because of the extra restriction that $m_2+2m_3=m$.

Comment: "By $C(n, m)$ denote the coefficient of $x^m$ in $(1+x+x^2)^n$". This is what I'm taking as your definition. Everything else is unnecessary for your question.