# Number of solutions to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=19$ with $0\leq x_i\leq 8$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, inclusion-exclusion

> Find the number of solutions to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=19$ with $0\leq x_i\leq 8$.

I know that I should use inclusion-exclusion, but I don't quite see why.

If I had this problem:

> Find the number of solutions to the equation $x_1+x_2+...+x_5=10$ with
>   no restrictions to $x_i$:

The solution to this would be $14 \choose 10$ (like a stars-bars problem).

Back to the first problem, I see why can't use that... Let's say I want to solve something equivalent such as:

$(x_1+8)+(x_2+8)+(x_3+8)+(x_4+8)=19$ with no restrictions to $x_i$.

That would be $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=-13$ which doesn't make sense as I'm working with natural numbers.

Can someone explain me why inclusion-exclusion applies to this? I understand the theorem but I don't get why I should use it on this.

Comment: Have you considered using generating functions? Like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477467/how-many-nonnegative-integer-solutions-are-there-to-the-equation-x-1x-2x-3x/2478262#2478262), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2514510/how-many-solutions-are-there-to-xyz-14-where-x-y-z-are-all-non-negative-in/2514527#2514527) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2886009/abcdef-14-where-a-b-c-d-e-and-f-are-whole-numbers-le-4/2886229#2886229).

Comment: @rtybase I can't really use it since i'm not there yet at my discrete math course :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stars and bars strategy is a good start, but it leaves you with solutions you don't want like $19+0+0+0=19$.  So then you use I/E to subtract out solutions where $x_1>8$, which is just like $(y_i+8)+x_2+y_2+z_2=19$, but of course there are more cases than that, and then you have to add back in solutions where two variables are greater than eight yadda yadda yadda. ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $A_i$ be a set of all $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ such that $x_i\geq 9$. Then use a PIE.

Answer (score 3):

One can apply a generating function approach
$$
\begin{align}
\left[x^{19}\right]\left(1+x+\dots+x^8\right)^4
&=\left[x^{19}\right]\left(\frac{1-x^9}{1-x}\right)^4\\
&=\left[x^{19}\right]\left(1-x^9\right)^4\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{-4}{k}x^k\\
&=\left[x^{19}\right]\left(1-4x^9+6x^{18}-4x^{27}+x^{36}\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+3}{3}x^k\\
&=\binom{22}{3}-4\binom{13}{3}+6\binom{4}{3}\\[9pt]
&=420
\end{align}
$$
Note that the last two lines are same as in an answer using stars-and-bars and inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: I just saw the comment that you haven't gotten to generating functions yet, but I will leave this for completeness and for those who can use generating functions.

Comment: Thank you! I'll later have to use generating functions on this type of problems so this will come handy:-)