# How many solutions does the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 = 8$ have?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

$x$<sub>$1$</sub>+$x$<sub>$2$</sub>+$x$<sub>$3$</sub>+$x$<sub>$4$</sub>+$x$<sub>$5$</sub> = 8

where $x$<sub>$i$</sub>'s can take values $\{0,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: `$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=8$` is a lot easier to type, and looks better too.

Comment: There are plenty [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477467/how-many-nonnegative-integer-solutions-are-there-to-the-equation-x-1x-2x-3x/) of counting techniques, but you need to tell us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: The answer is the coefficient of $x^8$ when you expand $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^5$, although in this case, you can probably enumerate the solutions directly.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it's easy to check by hand that the only solutions are 
\begin{align*}
   0+0+2+3+3&=8\\
   0+1+1+3+3&=8\\
   0+1+2+2+3&=8\\
   0+2+2+2+2&=8\\
   1+1+1+2+3&=8\\
   1+1+2+2+2&=8,
\end{align*}
up to permutations of the terms in the different sums. Thus the number of solutions is 
$$\frac{5!}{2!\,2!}+\frac{5!}{2!\,2!}+\frac{5!}{2!}+\frac{5!}{4!}+\frac{5!}{3!}+\frac{5!}{2!\,3!} = \boxed{155}.$$
It's easier to order the set of quintuples (say lexicographically like I did) when coming up with these.

Alternatively, you can construct a generating function for the problem, in this case $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^5$ is suitable, and study the coefficient of $x^8$, which is $\boxed{155}$.

---

If you are not familiar with generating functions, read [this short example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Zs8.png) of how they can be used to solve counting problems. They are a very useful tool when it comes to solving counting problems like this one.